# Mail function doesn't send mail in Django

Tags: django

I wrote code in basic HTML tags like and there was no problem. Mail was sent correctly. But when I changed its place and HTML tags mail function didn't work. What problem can be?

It works

```
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

It doesn't work.

```
<form class="contact-form" action="" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{ field|add_class:"input" }}            
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="button" type="submit">Send</button> 
</form>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = form.cleaned_data['fullname']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(fullname, message, from_email, 
                           ['gulnarnecefova1996@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Also include your view

Comment: @Sanip unfortunately I don't get any error. When I push submit button I see Ewerything was sent with GET method. But I used POST method in in the form

Comment: @Gasanov I included

Comment: In your not working form, you have specified the method as `post`

Comment: @Sanip I do not understand really. It works now. With both "post" and "POST" too.

Comment: Second form uses `method="GET"`, and your view will send mail only on `POST` request. That's why first form works.

Comment: I will try to clarify it in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form as you have stated `not working`:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{ field|add_class:"input" }}            
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="button" type="submit">Send</button> 
</form>
```

You can see that you have used `method="GET"`. Then in your views:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = form.cleaned_data['fullname']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(fullname, message, from_email, 
                       ['gulnarnecefova1996@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Here you have used the code for sending mail inside `POST method block` as:

```
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = form.cleaned_data['fullname']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(fullname, message, from_email, 
                       ['gulnarnecefova1996@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
```

So while you submit the form, it is being sent as a `get` request. And the `get` request is being handled by this block:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
```

Hence, the mailing function is not working.

Try changing the method as `post` in the html form.

Comment: Great thank you. And one more question I have. Is there any differences between "post" and "POST". I mean is there any effect of Initial letters?

Comment: Well in the html form method attribute, you can use both.